# Clang - invalid type for value

Tags: clang, llvm

I tried running `clang -S -emit-llvm test.bc` and I got this `error: Invalid type for value`. Does anyone know what does that mean? I get the same error when running `llvm-dis`.

Comment: How was `test.bc` generated?

Comment: First I loaded module with `parseIRFile` and than I used this function: `void llvm::WriteBitcodeToFile(const Module *M, raw_ostream &Out)`. I get the error even when I call `WriteBitcodeToFile` right after `parseIRFile`.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the version of opt that was used to produce the bitcode is different from the clang that you are giving bitcode to.

Assert that version of clang >= version of opt.